# check if data passed from laravel to vue exists

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

Sometimes I need to pass data from my controller to the view and sometimes I dont!
But when theres no data passed I get this error:

> Undefined variable: tutorial (View:
>   /var/www/html/resources/views/home.blade.php)

**No data example:**

```
public function index()
{
    return view('home');
}
```

**Containg data example**

```
public function tutorial()
{
    return view('home', ['tutorial' => 'Welcome to myproject, lets get started!!!']);
}
```

Blade:

```
beforeMount()
{
    let tutorial = {{ var_export($tutorial) }} // ERROR!!
    if (tutorial) {
        return
    }
    this.reloadData()
}
```

I think I can do this way in my index function:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('home', ['tutorial' => []);
}
```

But its just gross!! Theres anyway to check if data passed from laravel exists in my vue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you cannot just put the Laravel variable in js.

Options to solving the problem included:

1. Performing an api request for the data using the application
   component once it had been mounted.
2. Attaching the data into the
   Javascript context using the blade template.

You can do some thing like this:

```html
<Home tutorial="{{ $tutorial }}"> <!-- make tutorial become to props -->
</Home>
```

And in your view component:

```js
Vue.component('Home', {
    props: [
        {
            name: 'tutorial',  // add this props
            default: '',
        }
    ],
    beforeMount()
    {
        if (this.tutorial) {   // use like this.tutorial
            return
        }
        this.reloadData()
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! What about if I cant use props?? How can I get that {{ $tutorial }} in my parent component??

Comment: Get datas from components, u can use `datas` or `props` @Ricardinho